# How to get coredumps from php-fpm in OpenVZ VPS

Tags: debugging, nginx, gdb, php, coredump

I've the need to track down what is causing my nginx+php-fpm setup to crash on some requests. It's a quite big myBB forum so I suspect the problem lies somewhere between its modules. On the same host I have a Wordpress install too, but clients navigating there never get this problem. Clients get the 502 error sometimes only in the forum and I have this in php and nginx logs:

```
[15-Feb-2015 03:36:31] WARNING: [pool www] child 38593 exited on signal 7 (SIGBUS) after 136.848519 seconds from start

2015/02/15 03:36:31 [error] 38368#0: *2719 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: x.x.x.x, server: mydomain, request: "GET someurl HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "mydomain"
```

I tried to get coredumps for gdb but, since I'm in a debian VM under an OpenVZ host, i can't change the /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern value (permission denied) which is set to "|/usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp %s %c %p %u %g %t e" and I can't find any coredump anywhere (i have set ulimit -c unlimited already).

I also tried running php-fpm from gdb but at some time php-fpm just hangs without telling anything making my whole host offline.

I already tried a lots of suggestions found online, modifying both nginx and php-fpm configs, disabling any caching module and some other things without luck. CPU and RAM are not the problem, this box has 4GB with 3 free when this happens.

How can I get a coredump and track what is causing the signal 7 SIGBUS?

Comment: Have you found a solution already?

Comment: Seems like it's not possible in OpenVZ debian guests. I didn't try further, but my guess is that it could work using an RPM distro since they use /usr/libexec/abrt-hook-ccpp by default (CentOS/RH). My suspsect is that is better to use the same OS of the host on OpenVZ for compatibility of kernel values.